# PSWindowsUpdate remote permission issue

Tags: powershell

I'm running into an issue recently. I'm trying to use PSWindowsUpdate module to manage Windows Updates remotely on company computers. Getting list, install updates, delete updates and getting histories are all working fine either locally and remotely, but for hide/unhide updates, only works locally. When I try to hide/unhide an update remotely, I got "no permission" error. Here is the code segment:

```
$syncHash.PSWU_Show_Selected_scriptblock = {
    Param (
        [string]$cn,
        [System.Collections.Arraylist]$List,
        [pscredential]$cred
    )

    $worker = {
        Param (
            [System.Collections.Arraylist]$SelectedList
        )

        [string]$log_path = "C:\Windows\temp\BBC-log.txt"

        Import-Module PSWindowsUpdate

        Get-Date | Out-File -FilePath $log_path -Append
        "==================================" | Out-File -FilePath $log_path -Append

        $SelectedList | ForEach-Object {
            try{
                "UpdateID  = " + $_.UpdateID | Out-File -FilePath $log_path -Append
                "ServiceID = " + $_.ServiceID | Out-File -FilePath $log_path -Append
                UnHide-WindowsUpdate -ServiceID $_.ServiceID -UpdateID $_.UpdateID -Confirm:$false -IgnoreReboot -Verbose 2>&1 3>&1 4>&1 5>&1 | Out-File -FilePath $log_path -Append
            } catch {
                "Hide update failed." | Out-File -FilePath $log_path -Append
                $error[0] | Out-File -FilePath $log_path -Append
            }
        }

        "============ Done ================" | Out-File -FilePath $log_path -Append
    }
    #Wait-Debugger

    if($cred){
        Invoke-Command -ComputerName $cn -Credential $cred -scriptblock $worker -ArgumentList $List
    } else {
        Invoke-Command -ComputerName $cn -scriptblock $worker -ArgumentList $List
    }

    Invoke-Command $syncHash.outputFromThread_scriptblock -ArgumentList "Courier New","18","Lime","Hiding updates completed, please check log file for detail.",$true

    $syncHash.Control.PSWU_scriptblock_Completed = $true
}
```

$syncHash.PSWU_Show_Selected_scriptblock is called by the GUI thread locally and $worker is called remotely on a target. Here is the error message from the log file:

```
UpdateID = 8efd2c01-ff9d-4c21-b5e5-ffda43f8f2c1
ServiceID = 7971f918-a847-4430-9279-4a52d1efe18d
MyLaptop (2021-11-13 8:48:16 PM): Connecting to Microsoft Update server. Please wait...
Found [1] Updates in pre search criteria
Found [1] Updates in post search criteria
Performing the operation "(2021-12-13 8:48:26 PM) Show 2021-11 Cumulative Update Preview for .NET
Framework 3.5 and 4.8 for Windows 10 Version 21H1 for x64 (KB5007289)[65MB]" on target "MyLaptop".
Hide update failed.
UnHide-WindowsUpdate : MyLaptop: You don't have permission to perform this task.
At line:17 char:17

    ... UnHide-WindowsUpdate -ServiceID $.ServiceID -UpdateID $ ...

                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

        CategoryInfo : CloseError: (:) [Get-WindowsUpdate], Exception
        FullyQualifiedErrorId : 0x80240044,PSWindowsUpdate.GetWindowsUpdate
```

If I use -ComputerName in UnHide-WindowsUpdate command, I got the same error message. The only working way is to run the command locally on the target.

Command Hide-WindowsUpdate is the same. I have tested on either domain or workgroup computers and I do have domain/local admin account, I have actually no permission issue on any one of the targets on tried.

I was trying to get the PSWindowsUpdate module source code but it seems like it's not open source.

Someone actually asked the same question, but no answer so far:
https://superuser.com/questions/1634434/hide-windowsupdate-permission-issue

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It’s likely a double hop issue. I’m pretty sure Microsoft broke doing updates remotely. 

For my own use cases I’ve only ever been able to install Windows Updates remotely using DISM and the cab files for the updates themselves. 

Also is the module installed and imported on all the remotes?

Comment: Yup, installing PSWindowsUpdate module on the remote target is the 1st step. Just hide/unhide update has this permission issue, the other operations have no issues.